# Dynamically add javascript origin and redirect URI in GCP Api and Services Credentials

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-auth

I have an Api & Services project in Google Cloud. In that project, I have set up some credentials. Inside the credentials screen, there are options available to specify the `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs`.

I have specified one value each for these and it works fine. However, I want to dynamically add to these later on, so that there are more than one JavaScript origin and redirect URI. Is this somehow possible to do in Java? Can somebody point me to the documentation where it specifies how to modify an existing GCP project's Credentials?

I can get an active `Project` object like following, but I can't seem to find the way to get or update the `Credentials` that are inside a project.

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManagerOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
String projectId = "my-unique-project-id";
Project project = resourceManager.get(projectId);
System.out.println("Got project " + project.getProjectId() + " from the server.");
```